# Verify whether the next char is the same as first char

Tags: java, algorithm

I found a problem and i tried my logic but i failed to get to the solution.

This is the problem i am trying to solve in java.

For every opening brace (i.e., (, {, or [), there is a matching closing brace (i.e., ), }, or ]) of the same type (i.e., (matches ), { matches }, and [ matches ]). An opening brace must appear before (to the left of) it’s matching closing brace. For example, ]{}[ is not balanced.

No unmatched braces lie between some pair of matched braces. For example, ({[]}) is balanced, but {[}] and [{)] are not balanced.

I want to write java code which would take such a string input of braces and output whether it is balanced or not.

I am not able to apply logic for this kind of code, i tried however it was not even close to expectations. Please provide with some logic. I know this is not a homework completion site but i am stuck on the logic of this problem. a code snippet would be appreciated.

Comment: use a Stack for this.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with java. You need to use a stack to keep track of the order in which you encounter the brackets.

Algorithm-

1. loop over the input string.
2. If the current character is an opening bracket, push it in the stack
3. It it is a closing bracket, pop an element from the stack and if it is not the corresponding opening bracket to the current closing bracket then it is not balanced.
4. After traversing the string, if there is an opening bracket in the stack then it is not balanced.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String s) {
    Deque<Character> stack = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
        case '(': stack.push(')'); break;
        case '[': stack.push(']'); break;
        case '{': stack.push('}'); break;
        case ')': case ']': case '}':
            if (stack.isEmpty() || !stack.pop().equals(c))
                return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

No switch version:

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String s) {
    Deque<Character> stack = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == '(')
            stack.push(')');
        else if (c == '[')
            stack.push(']');
        else if (c == '{')
            stack.push('}');
        else if (c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}')
            if (stack.isEmpty() || !stack.pop().equals(c))
                return false;
    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Quite awesome solution compared to what i had done, but am having little hard time understanding the case statements. Would appreciate if you would explain how the switch case statement is working here. Thanks :)

Comment: Added no switch version.

Comment: `if (stack.isEmpty() || !stack.pop().equals(c))
                return false;` what does this line of code mean?

Comment: `!stack.pop().equals(c)` this thing i mean

Comment: `!stack.pop().equals(c)` means corresponding begin brace is different type.  For example `(]`.  In this case `stack.pop() = ')' and `c = ']'.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem.

This can be solved using Stack Datastructure.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String string = in.next(); //input string -> eg : {{[[(())]]}}
        boolean check = Paran(string);
        if(check){
           System.out.println("YES");
        }
        else{
           System.out.println("NO");

        }
    }

    //function that checks brackets are balanced or not
    public static boolean Paran(String string){
        //create a stack 
        Stack<Character> s = new Stack<Character>();

        //check if string is empty
        //if string is empty then Balanced
        if(string.length() == 0){
            return true;
        }

        //if string is not empty, go through each character
        for(int i = 0; i< string.length(); i++){

            //fetch each character
            char current = string.charAt(i);

            //check if that character id any of {([
            // if yes push on to the stack
            if(current == '[' || current == '{' || current == '('){
                    s.push(current);
            }

            //check if that character id any of }])
            if(current == '}' || current == ']' || current == ')'){
                //check stack is empty 
                //if yes then return false
                if(s.isEmpty()){
                    return false;
                }

                //else fetch top most item
                char pre = s.peek();
                if((current == '}' && pre == '{') || (current == ']' && pre == '[') || (current == ')' && pre == '(')){
                        s.pop();
                    }
                    else{
                        return false;
                    }
             }   
        }
        return s.isEmpty();
    }

 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Don't know why it was down voted, but thanks it works fine.